# How to send a state to multiple accounts in corda?

Tags: blockchain, corda

1.) I am making a project in Corda using the accounts library and I need to send a state to two accounts on different nodes in a single transaction. Is that possible in Corda and If yes then how? A flow code sample will be really helpful.

2.) How to create flow sessions for a list of parties in Corda flow or how to initiate flow for multiple participants?

3.) How to collect signatures from multiple parties in the flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Yes, you can. As described [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.6/api-flows.html#communication-between-parties) you can use:

- `sendAll(payload: Any, sessions: Set<FlowSession>)`: it sends the payload object to all the provided FlowSession. It would be associated with `receiveAll(receiveType: Class<R>, sessions: List<FlowSession>): List<UntrustworthyData<R>>`
- `sendAllMap(payloadsPerSession: Map<FlowSession, Any>)`: it sends a potentially different payload to each FlowSession, as specified by the provided payloadsPerSession. It would be associated with `receiveAllMap(sessions: Map<FlowSession, Class<out Any>>): Map<FlowSession, UntrustworthyData<Any>>`

2 - Flows have to be created for each party:

```
FlowSession session1 = initiateFlow(counterparty1);
FlowSession session2 = initiateFlow(counterparty2);
```

but then you can pass all of them to the same

```
sendAll(payload, listOf(session1, session2))
```

3 - You have to use `CollectSignaturesFlow(initiallySignedTx, listOf(sessions))`, which receives in input a list of sessions. You can take a look to its implementation [here](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/da73cbf2a5404d0720334b62d6f7f119d85caf45/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/flows/CollectSignaturesFlow.kt) and its unit tests [here](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/551b3f0811309e12261ce1c34f862f0a46e47dc0/core-tests/src/test/kotlin/net/corda/coretests/flows/CollectSignaturesFlowTests.kt), or an example of usage [here](https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/blob/03f14dcf535b376df9a513d3bdaccf25fbfe4acc/Advanced/obligation-cordapp/workflows-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/training/flows/IOUTransferFlow.kt).

Comment: Thanks for your help Alessandro, I have just one confusion. What payload represent here?

Comment: it can be any object type that you pass to the other party. Though, the other party needs to know what type you are passing to it.

Answer (score 1):

- In addition to Alessandro's reply, the Accounts library has a flow that is called `ShareStateWithAccountFlow`; which achieves your requirement.
- Please make sure that you carefully read what the flow does and how to use it with `accountQueryCriteria` (see [here](https://github.com/corda/accounts/blob/ed46fafa863ec1e5f58225236017d569345145da/workflows/src/main/kotlin/com/r3/corda/lib/accounts/workflows/flows/ShareStateWithAccountFlows.kt#L21-L43)).

Comment: Hi Adel, I tried my best to do it But I think I am doing it in a wrong way or I am missing something. It would really help if I get any example of a transaction involving multiple accounts in Corda.

Comment: There are 3 sample CorDapps that use Accounts library [here](https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Accounts), and the library itself has some examples (see [here](https://github.com/corda/accounts/tree/master/examples)). I'm sure one of those has an example with multiple accounts.

Comment: Another useful thing that might be helpful is to look at the `ShareStateWithAccount` flow tests that are also provided in the library to figure out how it works (see [here](https://github.com/corda/accounts/blob/master/workflows/src/test/kotlin/com/r3/corda/lib/accounts/workflows/test/ShareStateWithAccountFlowsTest.kt)).